# How do I use a variable from one class in another?

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

I understand this question has been asked many times, but I cannot seem to apply it to my code. In my code I have a variable called username in the class Ui_MainWindow, which I want to use in the class.

```
from viewAllRooms import Ui_ViewAllRooms
from teacher_menu import Ui_Menu
from viewAllRooms import Ui_ViewAllRooms
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Menu(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Menu, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.viewAll = Ui_ViewAllRooms()
        self.viewall_button.clicked.connect(self.viewAll.show)
        self.viewall_button.clicked.connect(self.hide)

class Ui_ViewAllRooms(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ViewAllRooms):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_ViewAllRooms, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.book_Button.clicked.connect(self.book_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def book_clicked(self):
        self._checked_items = []
        self.dialogBook.show()
        self.dialogBook.yes_button.clicked.connect(self.addBooking)

    def addBooking(self):
        now = QDate.currentDate()
        now1 = now.toString(Qt.DefaultLocaleLongDate)
        #I want to use the username here#

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def loginCheck(self):
        username = self.user_enter.text()
        #I have code here which connects to database to check username details
        #If the username is found in database then:
            self.hide()
            self.teacherMenu = Ui_Menu()
            self.teacherMenu.show()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.loginCheck()
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.loginCheck)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Ui_MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you answer, can you please explain how you did it, so I can understand.

Thanks

Comment: There is no variable named `username` in the `Ui_MainWindow` class.

Comment: I don't understand, perhaps I am mixed up. So what is `username = self.user_enter.text()`? @quamrana

Comment: You are assigning a value to a local variable, but its not something that belongs to `Ui_MainWindow` since it goes out of scope at the end of the method and is garbage collected.

Comment: @quamrana, do you have any suggestions as to what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Well, for a start, I'd need to know how you were creating and using an instance of `Ui_ViewAllRooms`.

Comment: @quamrana I have added this now.

Comment: You seem to have posted a completely different program. No, I'm talking about the first snippet where you declare `Ui_ViewAllRooms` and `Ui_MainWindow`, then you instantiate `Ui_MainWindow`, but not `Ui_ViewAllRooms`.

Comment: @quamrana, I am honestly not sure what you want me to add. I'm sure you know that all these windows are linked together via buttons. So I've imported the separate windows and then created classes for each of them so that I can open and close them through buttons. If I am not helping you answer this then I'll just delete this question.

Comment: How would I know the windows are linked together via buttons?

Comment: @quamrana The program loads the Ui_MainWindow, then once the user clicks the login button the program checks the details entered by connecting to self.loginCheck.
The loginCheck function then opens the menu window. In the menu window, when the viewall button is clicked it opens the Ui_ViewAllRooms window

Comment: Well, Now I can see what is happening. Pass the `username` to the `Ui_Menu` instance and that should pass it to the `Ui_ViewAllRooms` instance where `addBooking()` can use it.

Comment: How exactly do I do this, I don't understand what Pass means

Comment: :-O   Don't know what pass means?

Comment: @quamrana I mean I know what pass means, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code copied from OP but shortened to remove unimportant stuff.

Pass the `username` variable between the UI instances:

```
class Ui_Menu(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Menu):
    def __init__(self, username, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Menu, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.viewAll = Ui_ViewAllRooms(username)
        self.viewall_button.clicked.connect(self.viewAll.show)
        self.viewall_button.clicked.connect(self.hide)

class Ui_ViewAllRooms(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ViewAllRooms):
    def __init__(self, username, parent=None):
        super(Ui_ViewAllRooms, self).__init__(parent)
        self.username = username
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.book_Button.clicked.connect(self.book_clicked)
        #-----------#

    def addBooking(self):
        now = QDate.currentDate()
        now1 = now.toString(Qt.DefaultLocaleLongDate)
        #Use self.username here#

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def loginCheck(self):
        username = self.user_enter.text()
        #I have code here which connects to database to check username details
        #If the username is found in database then:
            self.hide()
            self.teacherMenu = Ui_Menu(username)
            self.teacherMenu.show()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.loginCheck()
        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.loginCheck)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Ui_MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Search this answer for `username` to see how it is passed around.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This seems much more complicated than I thought, I appreciate you walking me through this

Answer (score 0):

Add this variable to the object attributes by using `self`:
`self.username = self.user_enter.text()`. So you can use it in an other method of the class using `self.username`.

Comment: Is this going to help with using the username in a different class or is this only so that the username can be used within the class?

Comment: @Taf It is usable within the class by using `self.username` and outside by using `your_ui_main_window_instance.username`